# SharePoint Open "EditForm" in InfoPath

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, infopath

I have SharePoint 2010 with InfoPath 2010 installed and both work as intended. I can open my DispForm in InfoPath by either clicking the button on the SharePoint website or the Design Forms in InfoPath button in SharePoint designer.

My question is, how do I open or edit an existing EditForm.aspx within InfoPath?

If I go to the SharePoint document list online and then click on List > Form Web Parts, I can open the (ITEM) Edit Form, but I need to open it in InfoPath.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer I was looking for. You CAN open these forms in InfoPath. What you need to do is Open your original Item DispForm in InfoPath. Then click on Page Design in the upper ribbon. Under the "View" change it to Edit Item or create a new view.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, The **Customize form** button is not available in SharePoint Online.

So you should first save a copy from the published template as (a working Copy) in your computer then open this working copy via InfoPath.

To Save a copy of the form template from a list to your computer, just

- Navigate to the your list, in the URL replace `allitmes.aspx` to `/item/template.xsn`
- This will ask you to save a template.> save it on your computer.
- Right click on the `template.xsn` and select **Design** to open your template via InfoPath.
- Do your changes and click save, that should reflect your changes directly to your form in SharePoint.

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow. Even though I am using SharePoint Online, I still have all of the same functionality and tools as SharePoint 2013/2010. So there is no way to open the existing SharePoint EditForm into InfoPath?

Comment: Perhaps it will help if I explain with a picture. I have a SharePoint 2010 list. If I click on the List tap at the top, I get this option here: http://imgur.com/a/U7EdH In return, this opens the Web part or Edit Form in the browser. Great for when editing small details, but larger changes are nearly impossible. What I would like to do is open this (Item) Edit Form into InfoPath so I can manage the rules, fields, and text.

Comment: are you have Customize form in InfoPath in SharePoint online ?!!it's  available for SharePoint 2010 / 2013 on-prem, but as I mentioned not available in online, so to can edit your form via InfoPath , you should take a copy from the published InfoPath template as I mentioned in my answer  , please don't hesitate to tell me which step you are stuck !